Android Studio suddenly doesn't build project anymore
I had a Kotlin project working well.
Then I changed the version info string and got always errors if I build the project.
Then I tried to create a new Kotlin project Empty Views Activity and copy my old source in it. But I can't even compile the emty new project.
I guess gradle or something else was updated and causes this errors.
I already tried to delete .gradle .idea Invalidate Caches. But nothing helped.
What to do? I'm not a gradle or something like that developer.
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 973 ms

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Exception while analyzing expression in (6,1) in C:/Users/oschi/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8738583626161593103.tmp/build.gradle.kts
  
  Attachments:
  causeThrowable
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not read file: C:/Users/oschi/.gradle/caches/8.6/kotlin-dsl/accessors/2a70e4a6d31e5cb3896e8542863d3c87/classes/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/TestDebugImplementationDependenciesMetadataConfigurationAccessorsKt.class; size in bytes: 5534; file type: CLASS
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory.logFileReadingErrorMessage(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:77)

.....

    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readStringish(ClassReader.java:3706)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:3721)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.FileBasedKotlinClass.create(FileBasedKotlinClass.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory$create$1.invoke(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:57)
    ... 370 more
  
  ----
  expression.kt
  <File name: build.gradle.kts, Physical: true>
  <ELEMENT>android {
      namespace = "com.sico.blabla"
      compileSdk = 34
  
      defaultConfig {
          applicationId = "com.sico.blabla"
          minSdk = 28
          targetSdk = 34
          versionCode = 1
          versionName = "1.0"
  
          testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }
  
      buildTypes {
          release {
              isMinifyEnabled = false
              proguardFiles(
                  getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                  "proguard-rules.pro"
              )
          }
      }
      compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
          targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      }
      kotlinOptions {
          jvmTarget = "1.8"
      }
  }</ELEMENT>
  
  dependencies {
  
      implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
      implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
      implementation(libs.material)
      implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
      implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
      testImplementation(libs.junit)
      androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
      androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
  }

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$500(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)

.....

    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readStringish(ClassReader.java:3706)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:3721)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.FileBasedKotlinClass.create(FileBasedKotlinClass.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory$create$1.invoke(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:57)
    ... 370 more

----
expression.kt
<File name: build.gradle.kts, Physical: true>
<ELEMENT>android {
    namespace = "com.sico.blabla"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.sico.blabla"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}</ELEMENT>

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.logOrThrowException(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.lambda$getTypeInfo$0(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:90)

.....

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.lambda$getTypeInfo$0(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:176)
    ... 300 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readStringish(ClassReader.java:3706)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:3721)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.FileBasedKotlinClass.create(FileBasedKotlinClass.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory$create$1.invoke(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:57)
    ... 365 more

==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Failed to query the value of property 'buildFlowServiceProperty'.
> Could not isolate value org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.BuildFlowService$Parameters_Decorated@8eae531 of type BuildFlowService.Parameters
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
      > Exception while analyzing expression in (6,1) in C:/Users/oschi/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8738583626161593103.tmp/build.gradle.kts
        
        Attachments:
        causeThrowable
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not read file: C:/Users/oschi/.gradle/caches/8.6/kotlin-dsl/accessors/2a70e4a6d31e5cb3896e8542863d3c87/classes/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/TestDebugImplementationDependenciesMetadataConfigurationAccessorsKt.class; size in bytes: 5534; file type: CLASS
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory.logFileReadingErrorMessage(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:77)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory.access$logFileReadingErrorMessage(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:46)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory$create$1.invoke(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:68)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory$create$1.invoke(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:51)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:90)

.....

            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
        Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
            at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readStringish(ClassReader.java:3706)
            at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:3721)
            at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
            at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:395)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.FileBasedKotlinClass.create(FileBasedKotlinClass.java:87)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory$create$1.invoke(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:57)
            ... 370 more
        
        ----
        expression.kt
        <File name: build.gradle.kts, Physical: true>
        <ELEMENT>android {
            namespace = "com.sico.blabla"
            compileSdk = 34
        
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId = "com.sico.blabla"
                minSdk = 28
                targetSdk = 34
                versionCode = 1
                versionName = "1.0"
        
                testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
        
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    isMinifyEnabled = false
                    proguardFiles(
                        getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                        "proguard-rules.pro"
                    )
                }
            }
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }</ELEMENT>
        
        dependencies {
        
            implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
            implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
            implementation(libs.material)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
            implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
            testImplementation(libs.junit)
            androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
            androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
        }

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException: Failed to query the value of property 'buildFlowServiceProperty'.

.....

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readStringish(ClassReader.java:3706)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:3721)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.FileBasedKotlinClass.create(FileBasedKotlinClass.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory$create$1.invoke(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:57)
    ... 370 more

----
expression.kt
<File name: build.gradle.kts, Physical: true>
<ELEMENT>android {
    namespace = "com.sico.blabla"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.sico.blabla"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}</ELEMENT>

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.logOrThrowException(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.lambda$getTypeInfo$0(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:165

.....


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not read file: C:/Users/oschi/.gradle/caches/8.6/kotlin-dsl/accessors/2a70e4a6d31e5cb3896e8542863d3c87/classes/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/TestDebugImplementationDependenciesMetadataConfigurationAccessorsKt.class; size in bytes: 5534; file type: CLASS
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory.logFileReadingErrorMessage(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:77)

    ... 300 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readStringish(ClassReader.java:3706)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:3721)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.FileBasedKotlinClass.create(FileBasedKotlinClass.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.VirtualFileKotlinClass$Factory$create$1.invoke(VirtualFileKotlinClass.kt:57)
    ... 365 more

==============================================================================

CONFIGURE FAILED in 1m 1s


delete .gradle .idea
Invalidate Caches

This error looks pretty close to this one I can't compile anymore: AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 0","sources":.
Probably some of used libraries have an errors inside and need to use newer or latest version of it,
check this first.
And let me know if this helped
